# The probability of the second two occurring before the fifth five

Tags: probability

We have a fair die, what is the probability that the $2^{\text{nd}}$ $2$ occur before the $5^{\text{th}}$ $5$? My thought was to sum all the permutations that the $2^{\text{nd}}$ $2$ is before $5^{\text{th}}$ $5$ over all the possibilities, but that would be overkill. I'm sure there's a elegant way but I just don't know it. May I ask for help in solving this task? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can ignore all results other than twos and fives and reduce the question to the following:

> We have a fair coin. What is the probability the second head occurs before the fifth tail?

So there are $k\le4$ tails and exactly one head before the second head. The desired probability is then a sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{k+1}12^{-(k+2)}=\frac{57}{64}$$

Comment: So simple and elegant, Thank you!